# Soldering capacitors onto a board that is spinning

Tags: soldering

So i need to solder a 4.7 uF capacitor in parallel to a 0.1uF capacitor to a very small pin of an MCU.

This is doable and I have done using tantulum capacitors, but the problem is that for the time being these capacitors are being attached to a prebuilt board thats application has it spinning quite quickly.

This often results in the wires breaking and needing to be resoldered, but each time it becomes more difficult and more likely i will bridge the pins. I have another board to use, how would I attach these capacitors so that they arent tugging on the pin and thus less likely to unattach?

Comment: After soldering glue them to the board?

Comment: soldering glue would not work as the board is very small and there is nowhere that the body of the capacitors can be glued

Comment: As @Spehro Pefhany says: show us a picture.  Before I suggest you just drop a whole dollop of hot glue it.

Comment: Since this is a mechanical aspect of a board with hundreds of restrictions we don't know about, whatever we propose has a high chance of you just saying "sorry, doesn't work because {new reason we can't know about}". So, voting to close as unclear until you add a photo.

Answer (score 3):

Okay, so the forces are too great. You have several (not mutually exclusive options):

1. Decrease the mass of the capacitor.
2. Improve the mounting.
3. Find a part with more sturdy terminations.

Perhaps you could substitute a (probably smaller) 10uF ceramic for the 4.7uF tantalum.

Mounting can be improved by using epoxy (but it's not easily reversible)

Maybe a leaded (through-hole) part would be sturdier.

Comment: hey, sorry but i am new to soldering, what do you mean by improve the mounting?

Comment: Show us a photo and we can talk about it. I'm speaking in generalities because there is a dearth of information. It would be good to indicate the axis of rotation, scale and approximate maximum RPM.